# react setstatus issue in the application

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change setState using button click. Please check my code

```
export class Mystate extends Component {
constructor( ) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        message:'Click Me Friends'
    }    
}

clickme = () => {
    alert('my alert');
    this.setState = ({
        message: 'Thank You'
    })
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
            <button onClick={() =>this.clickme()}>  Click </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I called the alert. It's working well, but state did not update. How do I update it?

Comment: `this.setState({message: 'Thank you'})`

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman i marked correct answer.. i did not check others answers

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman answer received as a comment. please check
@ Konstantin did it. its working for me.

Comment: @gihankumara Alright...

Answer (score 0):

The [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is a function and you need to call:

```
this.setState({
  message: "Thank You"
})
```

Remove the `=` after that in your code. Also, you can remove the following:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    message: "Click Me Friends"
  }
}
```

And replace with:

```js
state = {
  message: "Click Me Friends"
}
```

**Full Code**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Mystate extends Component {
  state = {
    message: "Click Me Friends"
  };

  clickme = () => {
    alert("my alert");
    this.setState = {
      message: "Thank You"
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.clickme()}> Click </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the updated object to your `setState` method like below

```
 this.setState({ message: "Thank You"});
```

Working Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-frost-gzcu1?file=/src/App.js:253-304

Answer (score 0):

Don't assignment. **setState()** is a method you need to call it.

```
clickme = () => {
    alert('my alert');
    this.setState({
        message: 'Thank You'
    })
  }
```

As you are using the arrow function you can avoid the inline arrow function here
instead of `onClick={() =>this.clickme()}` use like

```
<button onClick={this.clickme}>  Click </button>
```